# How to get two tableofcontents (general and detailled)?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, templates

I often see two table of contents in books - one for the big overview, one very detailled. I would like to have that too for a book based on [Springers](http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=1-154102-12-427299-0) svmono template.

I have numbered chapters and unnumbered sections in the book. The tableofcontent produced only shows the parts and the numbered chapters. That ok for an overview. I would like to have another tableofcontent behind the first one showing all the unnumbered sections too - is that possible, and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) packages. `titletoc` allows you to easily create partial ToCs; in this case, we can easily create a detailed ToC. The explicit option for `titlesec` was used to easily redefine `\section*` so as to include the section title in this new detailed table of contents:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\addcontentsline{ptc}{section}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\contentsname{General Contents}
\tableofcontents
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Detailed Contents}}

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section*{Test Section One One}
\section*{Test Section One Two}
\section*{Test Section One Three}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section*{Test Section Two One}
\section*{Test Section Two Two}
\section*{Test Section Two Three}
\part{Test Part Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section*{Test Section One One}
\section*{Test Section One Two}
\section*{Test Section One Three}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section*{Test Section Two One}
\section*{Test Section Two Two}
\section*{Test Section Two Three}

\end{document}
```

The two ToCs obtained: the one (general, short ToC) produced by `\tableofcontents`:

[image]

and the detailed one produced by `titletoc`'s `\printcontents`:

[image]

Comment: Great solution - works out of the box for me, thanks a lot! Only some of the section titles seem too long for the ToC, but I seem to remember a package like 'shorttitle' or so (?) that allows to give an alternative shorter title to a section.

Comment: @user17106 I don't know of any such package... Perhaps you could ask a [follow-up](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/3954) question?

Comment: There is already a related question here, I just found it, its simply done by: \section[toc title]{main \\ title}

Comment: @user17106 Yes, the optional argument works for numbered sections; I thought you were talking about unnumbered sections, which would require a little extra work.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `shorttoc`package:

```
\usepackage{shorttoc}
```

Now you can make a second table of contents with the name and depth you like. For example

```
\shorttableofcontents{Overview}{0}
\tableofcontents
```

This examples produces a TOC "Overview" with only parts and chapters. You can change the number `0` to a higher one if you like, to get sections and so on too.

Comment: Will this new "Overview" ToC include the unnumbered sections as the OP requested?

Comment: No, this method doesn't change the normal TOC itself. Springer itself uses

    \section*{Problems}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Problems}

in the template. If the OP follows this approach, the `shorttoc`method works. Otherwise he has to use your method (which also works with svmono).

Comment: @Ivo thanks for you answer - I used the other solution, but yours would have been a nice alternative too.

Comment: This works wonderfully and is much more elegant than the accepted answer, which doesn't work for me. Thanks!